# Deploying asp.net web api to azure app service

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

**Problem:** after deploying my asp.net core web api to azure app service I can't get a response from the expected endpoint

Steps followed:

- I have an api that works fine when serving from my local machine, developed using Visual Studio Code. (The code for that is here https://github.com/samrae7/blog-api FYI)
- I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8J_CRy2_XA to push the files up to Azure App services. Basically I used the VS Code azure app service extension to create  a webapp on azure and push my files.
- I can see my files have been pushed to Azure ( by logging in to the portal and looking) but when I navigate to the expected URL of my api, http://sams-blog-api.azurewebsites.net, I get 'site not found'. If I try to send a request to the expected endpoint (I append `/api/resource` as this is the path of the endpoints on my local machine) I get '404 not found'

So my question is what do I have to do to actually get my api up and running online after pushing the files to azure app service

Thanks

Comment: does https work?

Comment: No but good shout

Answer (score 0):

Your website is not accessible due to missing DNS entry. I check it using the mxtool
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3asams-blog-api.azurewebsites.net&run=toolpage#

[image]

Please ensure that your url is correct.

Comment: I deleted the web app when I was trying to fix this ( I was creating multiple versions) which I think is why the DNS doesn't exist ( sorry for not updating the post)

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer to this question was that I had not understood that you have to create a Database in azure for your deployed app to connect to, and you need to set the connection string as an env variable in azure so that it knows where to look, and you should also add code that automatically updates the database on launch.

This tutorial was what helped with that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb

I then hit another issue where the deployed app was still returning a generic 500 server error. By enabling 'Diagnostic logs' via the azure portal, and downloading the logs, I saw this detailed error: `The configuration section 'httpProtocol' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration` referring to a piece of config in my `Web.config`. I deleted it (I don't need it for now) and that fixed the issue